# How to improve performance of WPF application when adding new Pushpins to Bing Maps?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

Right now my application reads an XML with latitude and longitude nodes (7k of locations). With the slider user can select what nodes he wants to display on the map. Now, everytime that the ValueChanged the following code will execute:

```
foreach (HueDataClass dataClass in plotThumbList)
{
    Pushpin Lamp = new Pushpin();                  
    Lamp.Location = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(dataClass.Lat, dataClass.Lon);
    hueMap.Children.Add(Lamp);
}
```

Sometimes the application freezes for a second and then displays all the Pushpins.. How could I boost the performance?

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually adding Pushpins to a MapLayer you should use a [MapItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mapitemscontrol.aspx) and bind its [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property to an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) of your data item.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MapItemDataTemplate">
        <m:Pushpin Location="{Binding ...}" ... />
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:DataItemsCollection x:Key="DataItems"/>
</Window.Resources>
<m:Map ... >
    <map:MapItemsControl
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MapItemDataTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataItems}}"/>
</m:Map>
```

See also the Examples section in [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) and the links in there for how to bind to collections.

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. This is my code right now:

Pushpin Lamp = new Pushpin();
Lamp.Name = "_" + dataClass.ID;
Lamp.Location = new Location(dataClass.Lat, dataClass.Lon);
Lamp.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(Lamp_MouseEnter);
Lamp.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(Lamp_MouseLeave);
Lamp.Template = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("PinTemplate");


XAML:
<m:Map SupportedManipulations="Translate,Scale"  x:Name="hueMap"  CredentialsProvider="">
<m:Map.Mode>
<m:MercatorMode/>
</m:Map.Mode>
<local:MyTileLayer UriFormat="file:///C:/Users//tiles{z}-{x}-{y}.png"/>  
</m:Map>

Comment: @Niels Sorry, that is unreadable as comment. Consider editing your question.

Comment: Thank you, using MapItemsControl instead of Map.Children.Add dramatically increased the performance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to thread your application. Execute the code that add pushpins in a separate thread.

Here is some resources : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx
                         http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235678.aspx

You will have to deal with the fact that you can't udpate the UI thread from another thread. I know you have to play with InvokeRequired in WinForms, but I don't know for WPF.